# Angular2 Router URL breaks at &

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

After I updated to the latest angular v4.3.2 all my urls break at & value, for example I have an route /:value that I want to get the value from:

> http://localhost:4200/one&two

but it redirects me to:

> http://localhost:4200/one

And since the value from the url is dynamic, many can have & I cannot display the correct result.

Using an **CustomUrlSerializer** I managed to replace **%26** to be **&** and navigating thru the router inside the app works but still at initial page load the url gets splitted:

```
import { UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {

  parse(url: any): UrlTree {
    const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    return dus.parse(url);
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
    const dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    const path = dus.serialize(tree);
    return path.replace(/%26/g, '&').replace(/%2B/g, '+');
  }

}
```

Is there any solution to disable url breaking at & ?

Comment: Why do you need `&` in the URL? It is used as a special character in the URL and IMO it should stay like that.

Comment: Yeah I know its an special character that separates params, I need it since the value is dynamic and many contain special characters like & and I don't want it to be splitted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I know that & is used as a special character inside router but if you need to get that value and not split it:

Edit: **node_modules/@angular/router/@angular/router.es5.js**

```
var SEGMENT_RE = /^[^\/()?;=&#]+/;
var QUERY_PARAM_RE =  /^[^=?&#]+/;
var QUERY_PARAM_VALUE_RE = /^[^?&#]+/;
```

Remove & from that regex and it should work.